# HTML5 Video File Size

Tags: html5-video

I'm wondering what size file is ideal to use with the HTML5 Video Tag. I'm building a site for a friend and they have given me a file which is 80mb.. is this to large? What is a good size to aim for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer helped you, PLEASE set my answer as correct. Click the check next to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A broadband speed of 2.5 Mbit/s or more is recommended for streaming movies, for example to an Apple TV, Google TV or a Sony TV Blu-ray Disc Player, 10 Mbit/s for High Definition content.

One hour of video encoded at 300 kbit/s (this is a typical broadband video as of 2005 and it is usually encoded in a 320 × 240 pixels window size) will be:
(3,600 s × 300,000 bit/s) / (8×1024×1024) requires around 128 MB of storage.

Hope this helps. :)

I DO NOT think that `80 MB` is too big. Note that this totally depends on your internet speed (the average 2.5 Mbit/s). Like mine is 3 Mbit/s, so if most web streaming videos will play quite nicely.

It depends if your video is HD or not. It doesn't always matter what size of the file, because it buffers while the video is playing. It mainly matters what size the video is. As said above, of the video's SD, it will work well on most internet connections (the average is 2.5 Mbit/s, and some people have 3 Mbit/s like me), and more HD videos will require a much faster connection, something more like 10 Mbit/s (yeah, that's a lot!). Note that emerging technologies like the fiber-optics found in Google's new product, Google Fiber, would allow much higher definition videos to play with a lot of fluidity. (Google Fiber's connection speed is about 800 Mbit/s, I believe! Correct me if I'm wrong)

Tell me if this helps. :)

And click the gray check next to my answer if it does. :)